# Firewall security rule to whitelist IPs from which the Paypal IPN is sent

Tags: paypal

Our security manager wanted to setup some firewall rules to allow external traffic coming into the system only from known IPs. I am wondering the following list( from this url https://www.paypal.com/au/smarthelp/article/what-are-the-ip-addresses-for-live-paypal-servers-ts1056) is a complete list for the IPs sending out the IPN, also will Paypal keep adding more IPs to the list?

Will all IPN notifications come from an IP address that can be resolved to ipnpb.paypal.com?

```
173.0.84.8
173.0.84.40
173.0.88.8
173.0.88.40
64.4.248.8
173.0.92.8
173.0.93.8
64.4.249.8

Additional IP addresses coming later in 2014:
2.22.141.54
23.4.189.54
23.4.36.66
23.4.61.54
23.5.13.54
23.5.253.54
23.7.77.54
23.7.141.54
23.9.125.54
23.9.84.66
23.13.173.54
23.13.29.54
23.15.157.54
23.34.205.54
23.34.221.54
23.34.228.66
23.35.109.54
23.35.13.54
23.35.173.54
23.35.221.54
23.35.29.54
23.35.45.54
23.35.61.54
23.35.93.54
23.36.13.54
23.37.141.54
23.37.173.54
23.37.189.54
23.37.36.66
23.38.29.54
23.38.93.54
23.41.141.54
23.41.157.54
23.41.174.218
23.41.77.54
23.42.13.54
23.42.29.54
23.43.13.54
23.43.141.54
23.43.157.54
23.43.68.66
23.44.157.54
23.44.253.54
23.46.109.54
23.46.125.54
23.46.45.54
23.46.77.54
23.47.237.54
23.47.253.54
23.47.29.54
23.49.125.54
23.49.141.54
23.49.157.54
23.49.77.54
23.49.93.54
23.50.109.54
23.50.157.54
23.50.189.54
23.50.205.54
23.50.77.54
23.50.93.54
23.51.125.54
23.51.237.54
23.51.244.66
23.51.29.54
23.51.45.54
23.52.157.54
23.52.29.54
23.52.61.54
23.52.93.54
23.53.109.54
23.53.157.54
23.53.189.54
23.53.29.54
23.53.93.54
23.54.109.54
23.54.141.54
23.54.189.54
23.54.237.54
23.54.93.54
23.55.157.54
23.56.157.54
23.57.109.54
23.57.221.54
23.57.237.54
23.58.160.37
23.58.45.54
23.59.141.54
23.60.141.54
23.61.189.54
23.61.77.54
23.62.253.54
23.63.141.54
23.64.173.54
23.64.93.54
23.65.13.54
23.65.141.54
23.74.21.54
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is about setting up firewall rules, which isn't really about programming. Sounds like a good question for ServerFault though!

Answer (score 1):

PayPal can change IPs anytime. There's no guarantee this list is current or accurate. This is why PayPal callbacks to you (IPN, PDT, etc) have a way to verify the authenticity of the call.

Comment: The intent behind whitelisting the IP's PayPal uses to call your IPN script is an additional measure of security to ensure that it is PayPal talking to your script. Coupled with their verify call, validating deposit email, amounts, unique transaction, and status ensures that the notice sent to your script was pertaining to a real transaction. While PayPal does periodically alter IP's, it is very rare that the range changes for their notification to your script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a page about this in the docs now:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/faq/#ipaddress

> PayPal recommends using DNS to determine the IP address of our servers. However, if you must hard-code IP addresses to configure a firewall, refer to [What are the IP addresses for Live PayPal servers](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/what-are-the-ip-addresses-for-live-paypal-servers-ts1056) page on the Merchant Technical Support site for the most up-to-date PayPal IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

[List of PayPal IP addresses](https://www.paypal.com/au/smarthelp/article/what-are-the-ip-addresses-for-live-paypal-servers-ts1056)
In July 2020 the current IPs for IPN notifications are

```
66.211.170.66
173.0.81.1
173.0.81.0/24
173.0.81.33
```

IPN uses the notify.paypal.com URL

Answer (score 0):

Allow listing specific /32 will be constraining. Website site might owners might adapt different addresses as per business needs.

Looking at this PayPal's webpage, it now provides subnets... not anymore /32.
Leverage these subnets instead.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cshelp/article/what-are-the-ip-addresses-for-live-paypal-servers-ts1056

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).